# Unable to debug Node.js application in WebStorm using Serverless

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm, serverless, serverless-framework

I am currently creating a lambda function in Node.js and want to debug the code locally. I am using WebStorm as my IDE.

In my serverless.yml

```yaml
service: applicationsync
frameworkVersion: '3'
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x


plugins:
  - serverless-offline

functions:
  hello:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: get
      - http:
          path: hello
```

in my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "applicationsync",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/serverless offline -s dev",
    "debug": "set SLS_DEBUG=* && node --inspect /usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless offline -s dev"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "serverless-offline": "^8.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1170.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  }
}
```

And then I have added some screen shots.

I click on debug option:

[image: Pic 1]

The following runs:

[image: Pic 2]

My file structure:

[image: Pic 3]

When I send a request I get a response back but break points are ignored and debug is not triggered.

I am wondering what I am missing.

Comment: Have you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to `Edit Configurations...` and regularly `Run...` the app. [image]